# C# Application database layout

Tags: c#, sql, foreign-keys

I'm writing a zoo administration application, but i'm having trouble with making my database relations etc. I have 3 tables, Animals, Zones (Like artic or desert) and zoo's.

In the zoo's table there are all the zoo's somone owns.
In the animals table are all the animals and their details (Name gender etc.).
In the zones table there are all the zones.

What I want is that there is a zoo, that has a number of zones, for instance 4, and in all those zones there are animals.

Its easy to lay a relation between animals and zones, but how do i get it so that there can be multiple zones in a zoo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same as there are multiple animals in a zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use intersection tables:

- tbl_zoo (zoo_id, zoo_name)
- itbl_zoo_zone (tbl_zoo.zoo_id, tbl_zones.zone_id)
- tbl_zones (zone_id, zone_name)
- itbl_animal_zones (tbl_zones.zone_id, tbl_animals.animal_id)
- tbl_animals (animal_id, animal_name)

Here is a sample query:

```
    SELECT zoos.Zoo_Name, anim.Animal_Name, zone.Zone_Name 
    FROM tbl_Zoo zoos
    INNER JOIN itbl_Zoo_Zones zzoo ON zoos.zoo_id = zzoo.zoo_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_zones zone ON zzoo.zone_id = zone.zone_id
    INNER JOIN itbl_animal_zones azoo ON zone.zone_id = azoo.zone_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_animals anim ON azoo.animal_id = anim.animal_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be a basic relationship. You have access to the Zoo an animal belongs to by joining through Zone.

```
table Zoo: ZooID (unique), ZooName, ...
table Zone: ZoneID (unique), ZooID (non-unique, FK), ZoneTypeID, ...
table Animal: AnimalID (unique), ZoneID (non-unique, FK), AnimalTypeID, ...
```

I would recommend adding a ZoneType and AnimalType table as well

```
table ZoneType: ZoneTypeID, ZoneName, ....
table AnimalType: AnimalTypeID, AnimalName, ....
```

Let's say 2 zoos had the same type of zones - arctic and desert. Without the ZoneType table your Zone table would look something like this:

```
ZoneID | ZooID | ZoneName
0      | 0         | Arctic
1      | 0         | Desert
2      | 1         | Arctic
3      | 1         | Desert
```

Now this is fine if the only data associated with a zone is its name, but imagine if there's more information on a zone - now all that data is duplicated for every row. With the ZoneType table you can store a single ZoneTypeID on the Zone table without duplcation any data

Comment: How does ZoneType fit in? Maybe a stupid question, but i'm really confused